# Matrix moving other elements horizontally

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a matrix which shows me the sum of elements according to 2 data. I can have multiple rows but I know I can only have maximum **4 columns**.
Below the matrix, I have 3 rectangles with some elements inside. So the problem is that when I have more than one column displayed, the matrix is moving the elements below.

Here is the desired result:

[image: enter code here]

And here is what I get for the moment:

[image: enter code here]

Here is the Design view:
[image]

I have the good result if I only have one column displayed.

Why the matrix is moving the elements on the botom and how can I prevent the matrix to move them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the 3 matrixes below inside one rectangle.

Comment: It seems to work. But does it mean I have to put every elements below inside one rectangle (because I don't have only 3 rectangles)? Is there no other ways?

Comment: Rectangle fixes the positioning of the elements/objects. so it's a good practice to always put the elements inside one rectangle if they should be together.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will do this. And I could test your solution, it works!